# calculating degree centrality using NetworkX in python3

Tags: python, networkx

I am new in using Networkx, and do for python. I am trying to calculate degree centrality for the nodes (about 14K) from a csv file- the first column are source and second column is the target. Here is an example (these are ids of individual managers):

```
Source    Target
4890    12842691
4890    26682663
4890    59694886
4890    79419501
5280    389911360
5280    393411529
5280    395211613
5280    395511628
5280    395811643
5280    396011651
6000    300556269
6000    315027716
6000    315037716
6000    341189880
6000    341909932
6000    341919932
```

I have tried the following codes:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('man_edge.csv')
FG = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(data, source='Source', target='Target')
FG.nodes()
```

Then I tried to calculate the degree centrality:

```
degree_dict=nx.degree_centrality(FG)
```

The code calculates degree centrality for the IDs 4890, 5280 and 6000. But it also calculates degree centrality for the IDs in the second column, which I don't want.

example:

```
   ID         degree_dict
    4890    0.526490066
    5280    0.215231788
    6000    0.251655629
  473931    0.003311258
  2219536   0.003311258
   8053083  0.003311258
 12842691   0.003311258
13213108    0.003311258
```

How can I calculate the degree centrality for the IDs in Column 1 only and not for the IDs in column 2? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Should your network be directed?  I get the impression that it should.  In that  case there are commands that will return the in-degree centrality and the out-degree centrality, which would work.  But first, you'd have to take steps so that networkx knows the network is directed.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the nodes on which the degree view has to be returned. For example:

```
import networkx as nx
g = nx.path_graph(5)
print(g.degree([0, 1])) # return degree view of nodes 0, 1
```

Be mindful that [nx.read_edgelist](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.edgelist.read_edgelist.html) can be specified to create using a directed graph; per default it assumes that the edgelist is undirected

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Those other nodes are **IN** your network.  Degree centrality must take those other nodes into account.

You can extract the degree centrality measure from just the nodes of interest (those in the source column).

```
degree_dict = {
    k: v for k, v in nx.degree_centrality(FG).items()
    if k in data.Source
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. You are correct that I need to measure the centrality from just the nodes from Source column. But when I am using the loop that you have suggested, it gives me no value of degree centrality. I have now also noticed that my codes FG.nodes() returns all the IDs (both from source and target). Is this the reason that my codes are calculating the centrality values of all the IDs in both the columns?

Comment: See my answer; you are using a directed edgelist but readedge lists assumes undirected graphs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume your network is intended to be directed.  So an edge should exist from the first column to the second.

Then your code would become (notice the `create_using` argument when you read it in):

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('man_edge.csv')
FG = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(data, source='Source', target='Target', create_using=nx.DiGraph())
FG.nodes()
```

At this point `FG` is a `DiGraph`.  The first set of nodes has edges to the second.

```
degree_dict=nx.out_degree_centrality(FG)
```

This will calculate degree centrality based only on edges going out (not coming in).  The nodes that don't have out-edges will have (I believe) value 0.

I can't test this without your data file, so please double check that I haven't made an error.

Comment: Thank you for your time and suggestion. I have tried as you have suggested. But it returns the same as I listed in my question. It is also calculating the degree centrality for edges. Is there any way I can share a part of my data here?

Comment: Can you check `FG.out_degree(node)` for some of the nodes in your `Target` column?

Comment: It gives me AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'out_degree'

Comment: In the `nx.from_pandas_edgelist` command, do you have the `create_using` argument?  You've created a networkx `Graph`, rather than a networkx `DiGraph` (directed graph).